# React Error: Maximum update depth exceeded - simple example

Tags: reactjs, function, react-props

I am trying to use some functions in the master.js component. When I run the code below I get the error 
"Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

I got the error when I added the button in the grandchild component

```
      <button onClick={props.homeHandler()}>change home</button>
```

If I comment out the button the page loads (without the button) so the error is something to do with the function called in props.homeHandler()

Below is the full code

```
import Child from './child';

class Master extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      parentName: 'Parent',
      home: 'Flat'
    };
    this.greetParent = this.greetParent.bind(this);
    this.changeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
    this.changeHome = this.changeHome.bind(this);
  }
  //Event Handlers
  greetParent() {
    console.log(`Hello ${this.state.parentName}`);
  }
  changeName() {
    this.setState({ parentName: 'Paul' });
  }
  changeHome() {
    this.setState({ home: 'semmi detatched' });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is master component</h1>
        <h2>My Name is {this.state.parentName}</h2>
        <div>The State From the Master is {this.state.message}</div>
        <Child
          data={this.state}
          greetHandler={this.greetParent}
          nameHandler={this.changeName}
          homeHandler={this.changeHome}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Master;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import GrandChild from './grandchild';

export default function Child(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>the {props.data.parentName}</h2>
      <button onClick={() => props.greetHandler()}>greetme</button>
      <button onClick={() => props.nameHandler()}>Change Name</button>

      <GrandChild
        greetHandler={props.greetHandler}
        nameHandler={props.nameHandler}
        homeHandler={props.homeHandler}
        data={props.data}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import React from 'react'

export default function GrandChild(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>I live in a {props.home}</h4>
      <button onClick={props.homeHandler()}>change home</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `grandChild` you're calling `homeHandler` immediately on each render, causing state to update, causing re-render, and repeat. You need to follow the patter where this is within a function rather than automatically calling it.

```
<button onClick={() => props.homeHandler()}>change home</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Nick - My bad